# How to design the Embedding Layer in Neural Network in order to have a better quality?

Tags: deep-learning

Recently I am learning about the ideal about the embedding layer in neural networks. The best explanation I found so far is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182775/what-is-an-embedding-layer-in-a-neural-network) The explanation there well addressed the core concept of why to use embedding layer and how it works.

It also mentioned that our embedding will map similar words to similar region. And thus the quality of our embedding representation is **how close or similar that a group of similar representations from original space is in embedding space.** But I really have no ideal of how to do it.

My question is, how to design the weight matrix in order to have a better embedding representation that is customised for specific dataset ?

Any hint would be really helpful to me! 
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you know some concepts of neural networks and Word2Vec, I try to explain things briefly.

1, the weight matrix in the embedding layer is often randomly initialized just like weights in other types of neural networks layers.

2, the weight matrix in the embedding layer transforms the sparse input into a dense vector as explained in the post you mentioned.

3, the weight matrix in the embedding layer can be updated during the training process using your dataset along the backpropagation.

Therefore, after training, the learned weight matrix should give you better representations of your specific data. Just like how word embedding works, more data often yields better representations in the embedding layer. Another factor is the number of dimension(generally speaking, the higher dimension, the more degrees of freedom the model will have to learn the representations of the features).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation ! I also found [the tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/tutorials/word2vec/index.html) from tensorflow is really helpful to me to reimplement the embedding layer : )